# Hello World for C# + DirectX 12 + Visual Studio Graphics Diagnostics: How to stop at a break point in shader code

Tags: c#, visual-studio, shader, diagnostics

How do I set and stop at a break point in my pixel shader code?

I'd like to write my own pixel shader using C# and DirectX 12 and Visual Studio 2019. 
Some good example on how to get started seems to be [dx12-game-programming](https://github.com/discosultan/dx12-game-programming).
At least I got it to compile and run and it shows what is expected at very high frame rates.

Now to get to analyze what the shader does, I'd like to use Visual Studio Graphics Diagnostics. Following the official [instructions for setting it up](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/graphics/getting-started-with-visual-studio-graphics-diagnostics?view=vs-2019) has many unfortunate breaking details: The examples listed in the documentation either do not exist or do not work (lots of compile errors or crash of the Graphics Diagnostics engine) - and they are quite old with nothing for Visual Studio 2019 and nothing for DirectX 12. The most promising is the C# and DirectX 12 example above ([dx12-game-programming](https://github.com/discosultan/dx12-game-programming)) that works on its own. However, when run in graphics diagnostics mode it results in *'Playback of your application may be incomplete. "No such interface supported"'*.

So ... is there any example where I can see the Visual Studio Graphics Diagnostics actually working as advertised? Where I can set a break point, stop at it and see what the values in the variables of the shader code are?